# use an angularjs filter to parse an url is safe?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

In a web application my client side (angularjs based) receive json data from a web service. Json can contains a text field with some url; for example:

```
blah blah ... http://www.example.com blah blah blah ...
```

I need to render this link as html, so i need to replace urls with  html tag.
To figure out, following a gist post, i tried doing follow filter:

```
botino.filter('parseUrl', function($sce) {
    replacePattern1 = /(\b(https?|ftp):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/gim;
    return function(text, target, otherProp) {
        angular.forEach(text.match(replacePattern1), function(url) {
            text = text.replace(replacePattern1, '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>');
        });
        text = $sce.trustAsHtml(text);  
    return text;
    };
});
```

in this way, on html page i use:

```
<span ng-bind-html="tweet.text | parseUrl"></span>
```

and so work.

My question is how safe this implementation? Anybody could use this in malicious way? 
Maybe anybody could suggests me a better way to figure out this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I should be more concern if the parsing happens in the backend. If this happens on javascript side, I should be trusting to those who share the url.

Comment: Thank you Noypi for your answer. Why you say that? What kind of concern?

Comment: if parsing is done by backend, i think it is possible that a malicious code can affect the parser (that is if the attacker knows what is used in the backend).

Comment: I'd like to know something more specific. Could you show me an example please?